# Making a declarative mock explicit makes a stubbing in a totally different place implicitly lenient. Why?

Tags: java, mockito

It's really weird. Take a look at this MRE. This test fails

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.routeProcessor;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MockingTest {
    @Mock
    private EmptyClass emptyClass;
    @Test
    void test() {
        new ClassWithMockingInConstructor();
    }

    private static class EmptyClass {
    }

    private static class ClassWithMockingInConstructor {
        Object dependency;
        ClassWithMockingInConstructor() {
            dependency = mock(CharSequence.class);
            when(dependency.toString()).thenReturn("whatever");
        }
    }
}
```

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at com.example.dynamicgateway.service.routeProcessor.MockingTest$ClassWithMockingInConstructor.<init>(MockingTest.java:28)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.

    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:192)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

Replacing

```java
            when(dependency.toString()).thenReturn("whatever");
```

with

```java
            lenient().when(dependency.toString()).thenReturn("whatever");
```

helps (which makes sense)

But what *also* helps is replacing

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MockingTest {
    @Mock
    private EmptyClass emptyClass;
    @Test
    void test() {
        new ClassWithMockingInConstructor();
    }
```

with

```java
public class MockingTest {
    private EmptyClass emptyClass;

    @Test
    void test() {
        EmptyClass emptyClass = mock(EmptyClass.class);
        new ClassWithMockingInConstructor();
    }
```

Now Mockito doesn't mind an unused stubbing!

What on earth is happening? How can making a declarative mock explicit make a stubbing in a totally different place implicitly lenient?

Spring Boot 3.2.1, `spring-boot-starter-test`

Comment: I get the same behaviour with both versions (the error)

Comment: @tgdavies could it be due to a Spring Boot version mismatch? Please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictness can not be used with *manual* mocks.

As per documentation - https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/quality/Strictness.html#STRICT_STUBS

> Enable it via MockitoRule, MockitoJUnitRunner or MockitoSession. See
> STRICT_STUBS for the details.

Obviously we can add junit5 extension to this list as well. To make long story short - do not create mocks manually.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean I can mock anything left and right with no consequences as long as I don't use Mockito's extensions (such as `MockitoExtension`)?

Comment: @Hepoha you can do that, but it's not recommended. This restriction is considered to be a benefit, e.g. it shows you that you are doing something wrong.